Invocation/function crashed timeout error after deployment in Vercel/Netlify
Github repo: https://github.com/sparshak7/commerceStop
I had deployed my website to Vercel. It was all working great till yesterday. From today, I keep getting tons of errors, such as application has a client side error check console or server side error. Then there's the vercel 504 timeout, invocation error and so much all at once. Can someone check the code and figure out what's the problem? Is it just a server issue from vercel or the other things I am using in this project such as Prisma, Supabase, KindeAuth and Stripe? What am I doing wrong? I also got prisma issues today like prismaclientknownrequest error for prisma functions that were all working fine till yesterday
I am clueless, I commented some parts of the code thinking maybe it'd fix but it's the same. So many issues in one day alone, today I was just working on a pagination component and after that everything went downhill
